# Selecting the first lowest from a result set

Tags: php, mysql

I have this SQL statement:

```
SELECT A.service_code_id, A.job_line_id, B.job_code, B.description, C.type_text, D.job_no, E.status, C.priority

FROM job_line_services as A

INNER JOIN job_codes as B
ON A.service_code = B.job_code

INNER JOIN job_type as C
ON B.service_type_id = C.unique_id

INNER JOIN job_lines as D
ON A.job_line_id = D.unique_id

INNER JOIN jobs_in_list as E
ON D.job_no = E.job_no

WHERE E.status = "In Progress" AND D.job_no = 17301

ORDER BY C.priority
```

This works fine and it returns to following results:

[image]

This is great, however I would like to only select the first result, ordered by lowest priority. In the image it would be the first row.

I have tried using GROUP BY and ORDER BY, Selecting DISTINCT job_no, Using the MIN() function on different tables, but I always end up with last row in those results, that one with the priority of 4.

How can I get just the first result in this result set?

Comment: How about `LIMIT 1` at the end of the query?

Comment: That's true, but just for testing purposes I limited the query to one job number (job_no), so in reality this would have many more rows from different job numbers and I just want the first row of each, ordred by lowest priority

Comment: That's significantly more complicated (and a detail worth making more obvious in the question).

Comment: Here's the idea (but I don't fully know your tables structure and design to offer a full solution). after the `WHERE ... ` add an `AND C.priorty = (SELECT MIN(C2.priority) FROM job_type C2 <more joins> WHERE <match with the current row>)`

Comment: This is the most frequently asked question under this tag (it's also occasionally answered correctly, too). Nevertheless, if you're still struggling, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)